# how to set xdebug HTTP request from another client

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, remote-debugging

I'm using xdebug to debug a remote server. Let's say I have

- a server S
- a client to debug on IDE C1
- another client C2 which sends HTTP requests to server

How can I debug the requests sent by C2, on my pc C1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do that. Because xdebug connects back to you. So if you request it on one machine, then it will try to connect to the same machine. Unless you have same ip-s.
Edit:

The text below is for debugging on same server.

You must set unique session id for xdebug.

Example:
XDEBUG_SESSION_START=my_unique_session_id

Source: [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)

Comment: Thanks, I tried earlier but it didn't work. Probably mistyped or else.

Comment: Happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with this config:

```
# addr of server with debugger
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1  # or another debug server addr
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1

# as you wish
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

# must be set to 0!
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
```

So, if some client connecting to server, server will attempt to connect to `remote_host`. In this case `remote_host` might be server addr.